# MySQL port is already taken?

Tags: mysql, port, uninstallation

My system had MySQL at some point but I am trying to re-install it now. But I get this 
[The port has already been taken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNukh.jpg)

If I change the port number to something else [I get this screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWUcg.jpg) The problem is that I don't remember the previous password. Is there any way out of all this?

While I was uninstalling MySQL last time, I uninstalled it from control panel, and deleted the service using  the command "sc delete MySQL".

If it's relevant, I have WampServer installed. Please help.

Comment: i think you can leave the field blank

Comment: MySQL has already been installed in WampServer (WAMP means Windows Apache MySQL Php). Try to change the port number of MySQL during install, it should be alright. Or uninstall Wamp and install apache, php and MySQL manually, it is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

Check with 'netstat -ano' and 'tasklist' if you have really uninstalled MySQL. I bet you did not.

Comment: I checked. Yes, mysqld.exe is still running at PID 4240. How do I delete it now?

Comment: go to control panel and to services there - locate mysql and after checking it hit stop